# Azure Data Studio 'login failed for user '<token-identified principal>' with MFA Support authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-data-studio

While trying to set up access for a user to access a SQL Server via Azure Data Studio, they are receiving the following error message:

`'login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'`

The authentication type is 'Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA Support' (and the 'Account' for the user is found), the database to access has been specified, Encrypt is set to true and the Trust server certificate is set to true.

I've doubled checked to ensure there isn't more than one instance of this user in the AAD. No other users are having this issue. And I tried looking for solutions online for this, but I was unable to find any scenario like this.

Comment: Does ADS have the _Azure (Core)_ extension enabled? It's [required to be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/azure-connectivity#issue-azure-core-extension-is-disabled) so as to provide support for MFA logins.

Comment: Are you also specifying a database name in the connection properties?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have confirmed that Azure (core) extension is enabled. 

For the second part, yes, I do have them specifying the database to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

To login with azure AD user to your Azure SQL first of all make sure your AD use is an azure AD admin on the SQL database

[image]

If want another user except AD admin. Then user must be added in the database from external provider something like:

```sql
CREATE USER [test.user@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Then in Azure data studio select proper server, database, AD account and other connection proper.

[image]

Comment: Took me ages to figure this out. Thank you.